# Trying to run "npm run start" in VS Code's Debug on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-code

Normally, I run `npm run start` to run my program. I am trying to use the VS Code debugger to debug my program while running it.

Here's my launch.json file:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "(Windows) Launch electron",
      "type": "cppvsdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "npm",
      "args": ["run", "start"],
      //"preLaunchTask": "build:win32",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": true
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run this using VS Code the error I get is: `launch program '' does not exist.`

This all works fine if I use `node` under `program` for my debug sessions.

Other things:

```
$ which npm 
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm
```

I tried changing `program` to exactly that path but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm assuming based on the `which` command that you've configured VSCode to use WSL as the integrated terminal?

Comment: No, using git-bash

Comment: Wait, you;re using git-bash from inside VSCode?

Comment: I ran which within hyper to find out where npm was since it'll be executed by cmd/powershell by vs code. I was just curious where it was on the Windows system. It's not being run by vs code.

Comment: Where does this error show up? Can you post a screenshot of where the error appears on the VSCode window?

Comment: It appears after hitting F5 to run the program in an alert message box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194190/discussion-between-suhail-doshi-and-ifconfig).

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is in your "program" field, which is supposed to locate the executable files. Some common values are like `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"`

```
program - executable or file to run when launching the debugger
```

Comment: I can run npm from powershell just fine though.

Comment: `npm run start` is just starting the `start` script inside your package.json. Since you want to run it in visual-studio code, you will have to follow the standard of launch.json, which requires you to put the executable file in the field `program`

Comment: You can see the docs for more information here:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387

Hope this helps.

Comment: My npm run start just executes "electron ." which also fails.